# What is the cost to convert a javascript variable to jQuery Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes I see in Javascript functions that, if the conversion of a variable to `jQuery` is used repeatedly, then it can be assigned to a local variable first:

```
$variable = $(variable);
```

Is this necessary, and how much is the cost of conversion?

Comment: It is terrible practice to not cache jquery objects. It is slow, because jQuery is slow. Always cache the jquery objects when possible

Comment: It depends on what's in `variable`.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 If jQuery is slow, why would you want to call it repeatedly instead of saving the result in a variable?

Comment: That was just my moronic typing / reading :P Cache when possible.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 We are wondering what you think is slow? Is it the practice of redoing the $() or is it the practice of using a variable instead?

Comment: @LeeMeador I think they meant that *not* caching is slow

Comment: Not caching the jquery object is slow.

Comment: So using the variable is GOOD practice, not terrible practice.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache

Comment: @Barmar that's what I edited my comment into some minutes ago and after further clarifying that yeah ;-)

Comment: I don't know if this is the proper place to ask this, but... There's major differences between use:

var x = $(".blah");
and
var $x = $(".blah");

?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 see http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache/2  - curiously the version using `$(div)` without caching where `div` is a DOM element is actually fastest on my version of chrome.

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz No, there's no technical difference between a variable that begins with `$`. It's just a naming convention to use `$xxx` to represent jQuery objects.

Comment: @Alnitak interesting. So basically sizzle is the actual culprit here?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I'm not sure why `$(el)` inside the loop is actually faster than `$el` generating outside the loop.  Ah - maybe your benchmark is pulling in too many divs?  I'll edit it to ensure there's only one div being tested.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽  ok, new version at http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache/4 that now shows the expected result.

Comment: yep much better: http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache/5 :)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 you need to get rid of the versions using `$('div')` - I think they're processing other divs on the page.

Comment: @Alnitak What about `var $div = $(document.getElementById('foo'));`? :) I think that would be fastest.

Comment: @Alnitak it is not processing other divs on the page AFAIK (but please correct me when wrong). It's just that the generic selector is pretty crap (read slow). Selectors by id are always faster.

Comment: @Alnitak Just as a reference for fun: http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache/6

Comment: @Hogan huh what are you talking about? There is no `<div>`. There is only the selector for all div on the page `$('div')` or by id `$('#foo')`

Comment: @Alnitak http://jsperf.com/non-cache-vs-cache/8 ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 - ugh you are right, how did I miss-read that?

Comment: "Correct way besides using the uber crappy innerhtml" ROTFL... Thank you guys for the performance information ;)

Answer (score 6):

No matter what, storing the object is faster than having to re-instantiate a jQuery object every time you want to use jQuery methods on it...even if it's miniscule for caching `$(this)` or `$(anObject)`.

A term used to describe this method of "store now, use later" is "caching". The reason it's often called "caching" is because caching refers to storing a reference to something once and using that, without going back out to grab the same thing again, later (very non-technical, non-100% accurate description).

The major point is dealing with selectors. jQuery has to query the DOM every time, which is the expensive part. Generating the object and storing references isn't that expensive compared to DOM manipulation (and jQuery processing your selection in the first place).

If you're simply creating a jQuery object out of an object reference, it's not nearly as devastating, as the processing that takes place is the creation of the jQuery object...so it's really limited to whatever jQuery does for that. It's still good practice and still prevents some unnecessary processing. For example, this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("div_id");
$(element).someMethod();
// Later:
$(element).someOtherMethod();
```

is slightly inefficient, since a new jQuery object is created each time. It could easily be condensed to store a reference to a single jQuery object in a variable, and reference that.

The one caveat I can think of is that it isn't a *live* list of elements (if selecting DOM elements). For example, you may want to cache all elements with the class `testing-class`, like so:

```
var myelements = $(".testing-class");
```

But if another element is added to the DOM with the `testing-class` class, `myelements` will not be reflected. It will have the same, previous list. So in that case, the DOM will obviously need to be re-queried and update `myelements`.

To me, the best practice for caching is within a scope....not the entire page. If you are running a function, and it selects some elements, cache it at the beginning, and use that. But don't cache it globally and use it throughout your page; cache it for an execution cycle.

For example, I would do this:

```
function someFunc() {
    var elements = $(".class-stuff");
    // Use `elements` here

    // code

    // Use `elements` here
    someOtherFunc(elements);
}

function someOtherFunc(el) {
    // Use `el` here
}

someFunc();

// Some time later:
someFunc();
```

but I wouldn't do this:

```
var elements = $(".class-stuff");

function someFunc() {
    // Use `elements`
}

function someOtherFunc() {
    // Use `elements`
}

someFunc();
someOtherFunc();

// Some time later
someOtherFunc();
```

Comment: caching is an interesting term -- as you point out there is no invalidation of the cache so maybe it is not a good term to use.

Comment: @Hogan "invalidation" is only a relevant issue when caching is automatic. When it's done in explicit code, it's up to the application to decide when the data is no longer useful.

Comment: @Hogan I'm not sure what you mean. What "invalidation" am I referring to? Sorry, I'm just confused by that

Comment: @Hogan (possibly unrelated) I didn't even realize the OP never mentioned "cache". I guess I saw it in the comments, and that's usually how I refer to this anyways. I'll at least update the answer with an explanation

Comment: @Barmar - I don't believe anyone uses the technical term cache to refer to temporary storage which writes or reads **invalid** data.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: "Cache invalidation" just means (all or some of) the cache gets cleared eventually. In the context of JavaScript on a web page, it's not usually a concern -- the cache will be cleared as soon as the user navigates or refreshes the page. I suppose for a long-running SPA like a wallboard or similar, it might be more relevant.

Comment: But people often use the word to mean "saving something so you don't have to recompute it". If it's done automatically, we expect it to be invalidated when it's no longer correct; if it's done manually, the code decides whether it's valid and stops using it.

Comment: @DaggNabbit We're not talking about the browser's web page cache.

Comment: jQuery doesn't query the DOM when you call it to wrap a variable that already contains a DOM element.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I never said that, but I can see where that could be assumed with my description. It's a good point, so I'll add that in

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the variable is.  If the original variable is just a single DOM element then it's not *particularly* expensive - the DOM traversal has already been done so all you're doing is wrapping that element in the jQuery pseudo-array and attaching the prototype.

However if the original variable is a selector, then you absolutely should cache the result to avoid repeated conversions from DOM -> element list.

In any event, it's good practise not to repeat yourself, so caching `$(variable)` is just good code hygiene.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$(variable)` is being called anyway this assignment has basically no cost -- this is only storing a reference to the object in memory.

Purists might point out that because the jQuery object is now stored it can't be garbage collected, and this is true.  So I guess if you had **lots** of these it could cause a memory issue, but in itself it has no cost to speak of.

The **reason** it is done is because there is a cost associated with creating the object, that is the `$(variable)` part.  That if done many times could be expensive.  Store a reference to the object means only one needs to be created.

Another important point:  The following statement

```
var $variable = $(variable);
```

could act different if it is done in a calling context of a closure.  That is if there is a function defined in the scope of the var statement that variable will "stick around" for the function to use.  This could have the same effects as described above (no gc and pointer memory) with the addition of a longer lifetime.  (Because it will stay as long as the function has potential to be called.)

Comment: When the scope of `$variable` ends the object can be garbage collected, so that shouldn't be much of a problem unless you put it in a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar -- sure looks like the OP's example is using global storage to me.

Comment: But he said "assigned to a local variable". I don't think he was really considering the distinction.

Comment: @Barmar - I could go bonkers trying to guess what posters really mean.  But I covered both var and non var in my answer.